# struggling with sshj example ('exec') : Could not verify `ssh-rsa` host key with fingerprint

Tags: fingerprint, sshj

I'm trying to write a java program that will connect via ssh and do some stuff on a server at work (redhat linux).  My box is windows.  I read about sshj and I'm trying to get the example to work.  I've worked through most of the dependencies and now I have an error dealing with public/private keys and unfortunately I don't know much there either (yes, it's a perfect storm of newbie-ness!).  Here's the error:

Exception in thread "main" net.schmizz.sshj.transport.TransportException: [HOST_KEY_NOT_VERIFIABLE] Could not verify `ssh-rsa` host key with fingerprint `5f:d6:94:00:9e:ec:7e:34:6d:d0:d3:76:df:5e:dd:3d` for `myserver` on port 22

Here's the code:

```
import net.schmizz.sshj.SSHClient;
import net.schmizz.sshj.common.IOUtils;
import net.schmizz.sshj.connection.channel.direct.Session;
import net.schmizz.sshj.connection.channel.direct.Session.Command;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

/** This examples demonstrates how a remote command can be executed. */
public class sshBuddy {

    public static void main(String... args)
            throws IOException {
        final SSHClient ssh = new SSHClient();
        ssh.loadKnownHosts();
        //ssh.addHostKeyVerifier("5f:d6:94:00:9e:ec:7e:34:6d:d0:d3:76:df:5e:dd:3d");

        ssh.connect("myserver");
        try {
            ssh.authPublickey(System.getProperty("myusername"));
            final Session session = ssh.startSession();
            try {
                final Command cmd = session.exec("ping -c 1 google.com");
                System.out.println(IOUtils.readFully(cmd.getInputStream()).toString());
                cmd.join(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
                System.out.println("\n** exit status: " + cmd.getExitStatus());
            } finally {
                session.close();
            }
        } finally {
            ssh.disconnect();
        }
    }

}
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 9):

just try this

```
ssh.addHostKeyVerifier(new PromiscuousVerifier());
```

this should work

Comment: This is not a solution. You are basically saying to disable host key verification as such.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
    public class sshBuddy {

    public static void main(String... args)
            throws IOException {
        final SSHClient ssh = new SSHClient();
        //ssh.loadKnownHosts();
        ssh.addHostKeyVerifier("5f:d6:94:00:9e:ec:7e:34:6d:d0:d3:76:df:5e:dd:3d");

        ssh.connect("myserver");
        try {
            ssh.authPublickey(System.getProperty("myusername"));
            final Session session = ssh.startSession();
            try {
                final Command cmd = session.exec("ping -c 1 google.com");
                System.out.println(IOUtils.readFully(cmd.getInputStream()).toString());
                cmd.join(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
                System.out.println("\n** exit status: " + cmd.getExitStatus());
            } finally {
                session.close();
            }
        } finally {
            ssh.disconnect();
        }
    }
}
```

Uncomment the addHostKeyVerifier and comment loadKnownHosts. It should work.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
ssh.addHostKeyVerifier("MD5:5f:d6:94:00:9e:ec:7e:34:6d:d0:d3:76:df:5e:dd:3d")
```

The method *addHostKeyVerifier* can receive as a parameter a **final String** which is used to perform a validation in the class [FingerprintVerifier.java](https://github.com/hierynomus/sshj/blob/master/src/main/java/net/schmizz/sshj/transport/verification/FingerprintVerifier.java).

According to [the repo](https://github.com/hierynomus/sshj/blob/master/src/main/java/net/schmizz/sshj/SSHClient.java), other inputs can be used such as:

- `"SHA1:2Fo8c/96zv32xc8GZWbOGYOlRak="`
- `"SHA256:oQGbQTujGeNIgh0ONthcEpA/BHxtt3rcYY+NxXTxQjs="`
- `"MD5:d3:5e:40:72:db:08:f1:6d:0c:d7:6d:35:0d:ba:7c:32"`
- `"d3:5e:40:72:db:08:f1:6d:0c:d7:6d:35:0d:ba:7c:32"`

In case of having multiple keys, double check the fingerprint of the **default public key** of the ssh server.